# Why does this terminal escape sequence fill the screen with Es?

Tags: terminal

The terminal escape sequence `ESC # 8` fills the screen with the letter E in multiple terminal emulators, including xterm and macOS Terminal. This can be seen by typing this in bash:

```bash
printf "\033#8"
```

Why was this added? The [screen user manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Control-Sequences.html) states that this function is called "Fill Screen with E's", and that it is VT100-specific, but does not give any information on the history of this escape sequence.

Comment: To test the terminal (the display). (Cf. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_card )